# Why is this not working VBA? Select variable active ranges for multiple find and replace

Tags: arrays, excel, replace, vba

For 400 successive and contiguous ranges of two columns (from line 2 to 26), I need to make 400 different changes.  All ranges contain "$3" within strings in many of the cell, part that needs to be replaced by "$x" and where x increases by 1 unit after each find and replace iteration ("each jump to the next two columns to the right, each ranges are 2 column wide).

This is the first time I use VBA have looked in many place within and outside stackoverflow and tried different routines all day. The routine below has a bug with Active Sheet and Replace functions. Thank you for your help.

```
 Dim lCount, lCol, lRepl As Integer
 Dim fFind, dOllar, cOntentRpl As String
 Dim RangeforRepl As Range

 lCol = 0
 lRepl = 4
 fFind = "$3"
 dOllar = "$"

 For lCount = 1 To 400 Step 1

    lCol = lCol + 2            'jump of two columns each time
    lRepl = lRepl + 1            'adjust variable element of replacement value

    cOntentRpl = “dOllar” & “lRepl”  'replacement value, starts with "$5"

      RangeforRepl = ActiveSheet.Range(cells(2, 2),cells(26.3).
      Offset(0, "lCol").Select      ' Select range where find & replace should take place

      Worksheets("Sheet1").RangeforRepl.Replace _ 
      What:="fFind", Replacement:="cOntentRpl", _ 
      LookAt:=2                                   'find and replace


 Next lCount
```

Cheers

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your data? Also I see few errors. `1` dOllar is a variable but you ar eusing it as a string object when you say  “dOllar” & “lRepl” `2` RangeforRepl is a range object but you are not using `Set` to assign range to it...

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be working (no bugs) but cannot see any changes in active sheet.  I cannot add my screen shot here. How do I do this? Thank you again.

Comment: upload it to wikisend.com and share the ink here :)

Comment: here is the screen shot http://wikisend.com/download/440070/Screen Shot 2015-05-14 at 12.26.12.JPG

Answer (score 1):

Change `RangeforRepl = ActiveSheet.Range(cells(2, 2),cells(26.3).Offset(0, "lCol").Select`

to

`Set RangeforRepl = ActiveSheet.Range(cells(2, 2),cells(26.3).Offset(0,"lCol")`

`Range`s are objects, and need to be defined using the `Set` keyword.

Also `cOntentRpl = “dOllar” & “lRepl”` should be `cOntentRpl = dOllar & lRepl`

Comment: Hi, many thanks again. I did apply the changes and to make it work I had to name the range ('test').  Then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the help I received, here is the code that solved my problem:

```
Dim lCount, lCol, lRepl As Integer
Dim fFind, dOllar, cOntentRpl As String
Dim rAngeforRepl As Range

lCol = 0
lRepl = 10
fFind = "$3"
dOllar = "$"

For lCount = 1 To 10 Step 1

lCol = lCol + 2
lRepl = lRepl + 1

cOntentRpl = dOllar & lRepl

Set rAngeforRepl = ActiveSheet.Range("Basis").Offset(0, lCol)

rAngeforRepl.Replace fFind, cOntentRpl, xlPart

Next lCount
```